# Docker Toolbox TLSParameterError

Tags: docker, parameters, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I was trying to use Docker Toolbox to develop a web page, so I did use `docker-compose build` but it gave me this issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 124, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 38, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 84, intls_config_from_options
  File "site-packages\docker\tls.py", line 81, in __init__

docker.errors.TLSParameterError: Path to a certificate and key files must be provided through the client_config param. TLS configurations should map the Docker CLI client configurations. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/ for API details.

[11432] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I'm new with this

Comment: Simply providing error code isn't enough. What have you researched so far? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: You should provide more information about the context of your problem.  At a minimum I would recommend https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/ to get a better idea of how docker's networking works.

Comment: I got exactly the same error with a brand new Docker Desktop installation. All the settings are default.

Comment: After researching my setup more, I noticed that I had existing docker environment variables from an old installation. After removing them and reinstalling Docker Desktop, everything works as expected.

Comment: @Aaaron where were the old files stored that you removed?

Comment: @Orcra They were in my shell profile file (config.fish). If you've done similar steps, check your .bash_profile or the equivalent for the shell you're using.